# Mustache PHP - is it possible to iterate over two arrays

Tags: php, mustache, mustache.php

I have a scenario where i want to shows the hours that various employees worked in a given week in a summary table. The structure of the sample data is shown below

```
$days = {'Mon','Tues','Wed','Thurs','Fri','Sat'}; // list of working days
$employees = { // the hours for each employee and day
    {'Mon'=>'4h','Fri'=>'8h'}; 
    {'Mon'=>'4h','Tues'=>'8h','Thurs'=>'8h','Sat'=>'2h'}
};
```

I'm using this mustache template to build the 'table' and the first row of 'day' column headers.

```
<table width="100%" class=" table-1">

// display all the days
<thead>
    <tr>
    {{# days }}
    <th>{{ . }}</th>
    {{/ days }}
    </tr>
</thead>

// sudo logic??
{{#employee}} // list all the employee's
<tr>
    {{# days }} // iterate all the days
        {{#employee.day==.}} // if employee this day 
            <td>{{employee.hours}}</td>
        {{/}}
        else
            <td></td>// empty cell
    {{/ days }}
</tr>
{{/employee}}

</table>
```

I'm wondering is it possible to use matching logic to ensure each 'hours' field of the 'employee' array appears under the correct 'day' column. I appreciate re-structuring the data in the arrays could make the template simple for the moment let's assume i can't.

Comment: You actually wrote it correctly. What is the problem?

Comment: I haven't actually implemented the solution yet since i expected to lose a load of time trying something that wouldn't work. Do i not need to restructure the 'employees' array to include 'day' and 'hour' keys to that mustache can correctly identify the correct value?